# Error in console when using the Waze iFrame

Tags: waze

when I use the waze Iframe I get an error when trying to load LivemapConfig:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

I can see this error when you open any web page with embedded waze map in it, even the official waze page and Guides
see :
https://developers.google.com/waze/iframe
https://www.waze.com/

Comment: What's the question!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.